# Rspec with capybara facing issue with page.should have_content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I am new to Rspec and here I am trying to test one of the integration test. When I (Using Capybara) clicks button then page content gets replaced with post response. Now i am checking for page content, it present on the page but still my test is failing.
Below is the spec

```
it "get force check takeover1" do
    visit('/las_xml')
    select('Showroom', :from => 'urlVal')
    fill_in('fpHeaderForce', :with => 'PSD.L.Syn')
    fill_in('currentDate', :with => '2013-09-11')
    click_button('submit')
    page.should have_content('Buy 2013 Labor Law Posters')
end
```

But Result is,

```
1) las box get force check takeover1
   Failure/Error: page.should have_content('Test page')
   expected #has_content?("Buy 2013 Labor Law Posters") to return true, got false
   # ./integration/las_box_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and resulted response html contains,

```
<div class="las-link" id="">
    <div class="laborLink_actual labor_01">
        <span class="laborLink"></span>
        <a href="#">Buy 2013 Labor Law Posters</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confuse about the "/las_xml" route. Does this mean that you get a xml file after clicking button ? Also, ensure your element is visible, `#have_content` returns false if it's hidden.

Comment: No this is just a name, as I am sending XML as a part of ajax post data and replacing same page html with response html, and yes element is visible on the page.

Answer (score 6):

### Possible causes

Provided you're indeed testing a html page as your result excerpt seems to show, there may be several possibilities, here :

1. the text you're trying to test is not the actual one. Double check there's no typo and you use the same locale if multiple language website
2. the element containing the text may be hidden. Capybara won't consider the content to exist if it is not visible
3. the previous click on button may simply not work or may lead to an other page

### Ways to isolate problem

As often with capybara since fails are just symptoms of real problem, we can deal with all problems using debugging features :

- `page.save_screenshot( filename )` : saves a screenshot to given file name (for example, 'shot.png')
- `save_and_open_page` : open an inspectable html page in your browser
- `binding.pry` : from `pry` gem, always useful to inspect context

For an example of screenshot creation through poltergeist, see [this](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#taking-screenshots-with-some-extensions).

### Edit : dynamic page problems

As mentioned in comments, problem seems to be tied to javascript content editing.

You should still use debugging mentioned before to be sure to isolate your problem. Once done, you can use capybara's [#synchronize](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Base#synchronize-instance_method) method to wait for your content :

```
page.document.synchronize( 10 ) do
  result = page.evaluate_script %($(':contains("Post")').length)
  raise Capybara::ElementNotFound unless result > 0
end
```

The synchronize method will be retried for 10 seconds, as long that the containing block raises a `Capybara::ElementNotFound` exception (any other exception is not catched). So basically, here, we check (using jQuery) if the "Post" content is present in page, and retry until it is or until ten seconds have passed.

If element was not found, test will fail by raising an uncaught exception.

If element is found, you can now proceed with your regular test. This allow to add timing condition in specs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I have tried with very small words like "page" just for spell mistakes and others.
Also the element containing text is visible on the page.

There might be the issue like,
I have one template from which I am giving ajax "Post" call and replacing the whole content of the same page with the response HTML using innerHTML property. Because when i tries to search to search the text which was exist before replacing with response "test succeeds", but not for the new replaced Html. But I am not getting how to fix this.